# Label value selected in angularJs drop down list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select2

I had a label containing value `user.Rules` e.g . London

```
<label id="ruleId" for="Rules" ng-model="user.Rules" ng-hide="editmode"
    style="width:97%; word-wrap:break-word; overflow-wrap:break-word;">{{user.Rules }}
</label>
```

After click on edit button a drop down list appears containing the list of states e,g Delhi, Pune, London etc.,

```
<select class="form-control" name="user.Rules" data-ng-model="user.Rules" ng-options="option for option in nestedList" ng-show="editmode" style="width:100%; ">
    <option value="" style="margin-left:25px">-Select Rule-</option>
</select>
```

I need to set the selected value as the label value of drop down list i.e. London

How can I do that ?

Comment: What is the propertyname of 'the option' that you want to display? Can you show us what _nestedList_ looks like in your controller?

Comment: here's some example code using `select` and `ng-options` : [link](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/forms/select/) hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no sample code and sample data for `nestedList` is not available, so I assume the data as my own and created this sample.

I consider the `$scope.RuleId` contains the id from the database. I removed the `ng-model="user.Rules"` from the label and and based on the `$scope.RuleId` I find its equivalent value.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    <label id="ruleId" for="Rules" ng-hide="editmode" 
    style="width:97%; word-wrap:break-word; overflow-wrap:break-word;">{{selectedLabel}}
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="ruleDetails" data-ng-model="RuleId"
        ng-options="option.RuleId as option.Rules for option in nestedList"
        ng-show="editmode" style="width: 100%;">
        <option value="" style="margin-left:25px">-Select Rule-</option>
    </select>
    <div style="height: 10px"></div>
    <div>
        <button ng-click="editButton()">Edit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
function MyCntrl($scope) {
  $scope.editmode = false;
  $scope.RuleId = "001";

  $scope.nestedList = [{
    "Rules": "London",
    "RuleId": "001"
  }, {
    "Rules": "Delhi",
    "RuleId": "002"
  }, {
    "Rules": "Pune",
    "RuleId": "003"
  }, {
    "Rules": "Mumbai",
    "RuleId": "004"
  }, {
    "Rules": "Chennai",
    "RuleId": "005"
  }];

  angular.forEach($scope.nestedList, function(rule) {
    if (rule.RuleId === $scope.RuleId) {
      $scope.selectedLabel = rule.Rules;
    }
  });

  $scope.editButton = function() {
    $scope.editmode = true;
  };
}
```

The same code is added in the [Working Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/yli8YWBmqFFb6KRybuuw) for your reference.